# why is my ip showing up different than the ip in android phone menu?

Tags: ip-address

Why is my IP address showing up different than the IP in my phones menu? I went to an IP lookup site and it automatically detects your IP address but what came up is different than that of the IP in my phones menu.

Comment: That depends at least on what IP you've looked up on your phones menu, and how you're connected to the network. Your device has multiple interfaces, e.g. one for WiFi and one for mobile data, which of course use different IP addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Probably this is because the network you are on is using *NAT*. Because of the world shortage of IP addresses, most networks (mobile networks and Wi-Fi) don't issue you a globally routable IP address. They just give you an address that only works within that network. *Network address translation* (NAT) is a way of letting all those devices on the network talk to Internet, by using something like a proxy server that relays the connections. When you connect to a site outside the network, it sees the connection as coming from the NAT server (*gateway*), so it will show you the gateway's IP address.